# ¿Can I share the App that I have created in my Developer Account with Essential Sales Cloud license?

Tags: lightning-apps

I have created a detailed Salesforce application in my Developer Account, and I need to make it work in another organization which has Essential Sales Cloud.
Is there any way on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe." It will depend on the features used in the app, whether or not you're an AppExchange Partner, etc. In the general sense, Essential Sales Cloud orgs can install packages, both from the AppExchange and other sources, but the org must support all the features of the App in order to be installable. Without knowing the technical details, it's impossible to tell you if your specific app can be installed or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The app would be very basic as it will just have the objects Leads, Contacts, Opportunities, and some customized page layout. The problem that this has to be installed in 14 different organisations and it would be painful to do the same one by one. As you say, I am not an AppExchange Partner. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alberto Once a package is created, each org can install it. You can also deploy changes with Salesforce DX, or other tools. Lots of options available.